# Is ASP.NET MVC 6 framework/ Entity Framework 7 out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to learn asp.net MVC. I have been reading tutorials about ASP.NET MVC 5. However, I see a lot of challenges with the framework. However, I heard there are better feature/architecture in ASP.NET MVC 6.

Is ASP.NET MVC 6/ Entity Framework 7 out? If not, what is it the release date?

Comment: What challenges are you talking about?  Imo MVC 5 and EF6 are pretty good.  If EF6 is to heavy for your needs, check out PetaPoco.  Personally I don't use EntityFramework, I use SSDT and PetaPoco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to the [ASP.NET Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap).

I've copied the relevant section below for convenience.

(StackOverflow doesn't support markdown tables, so use the link if you don't like my ASCII table)

> ## ASP.NET 5 Schedule and Roadmap
>
> Below is the schedule and roadmap for ASP.NET 5. Please note that these dates and feature plans are all subject to change. As with any project of this size it is difficult to predict exactly when things will land. Even so, we think it's important to be as open and transparent as possible about our plans so that our users can have the right expectations and create their plans accordingly.
>
> ### Schedule
>
> ```
> |Milestone|Release week|
> |---------|------------|
> |Beta6    | 27 Jul 2015|
> |Beta7    |  2 Sep 2015|
> |Beta8    | 15 Oct 2015|
> |RC1      |    Nov 2015|
> |RC2      |    Feb 2016|
> |1.0.0    |    Q1* 2016|
> ```
>
> The November release candidate (RC1) will be a supported and production ready cross-platform release. Depending on feedback from RC1 we will ship additional release candidates as necessary.

Here's a link to the [Entity Framework Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap).

Again, I've copied the relevant section below.

> ## Entity Framework 7 (EF7)
>
> Below is the schedule and roadmap for EF7. Please note that these dates and feature plans are all subject to change. As with any project of this size it is difficult to predict exactly when things will land. Even so, we think it's important to be as open and transparent as possible about our plans so that our users can have the right expectations and create their plans accordingly.
>
> ### Schedule
>
> The schedule for the initial release of EF7 is guided by the [ASP.NET 5 schedule](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). While EF7 is not strictly tied to ASP.NET 5 (and has many use cases outside of ASP.NET), it is an integral part of ASP.NET 5 and it is therefore important that we have a stable release of EF7 to support the ASP.NET 5 release.
>
> ```
> |Milestone|Release Date|
> |---------|------------|
> |Beta7    | 31 Aug 2015|
> |Beta8    |  5 Oct 2015|
> |RC1      |    Nov 2015|
> |7.0.0    |     Q1 2016|
> ```
>
> The November release candidate (RC1) will be a supported and production ready cross-platform release. Depending on feedback from RC1 we will ship additional release candidates as necessary.

Comment: I am still not too clear on the release date. does "Beta6    | 27 Jul 2015" means MVC 6 beta? when will it be in production? and for the entity framework is "|Beta7    | 31 Aug 2015" is the beta release of 7? when will it be production?

Comment: @Jaylen No, *Beta6* means "The 6th beta of the upcoming version".  Immediately after both tables there's a paragraph stating that *RC1* (which came out in November of last year) is a supported, production-ready release.  It's still "beta" (well, it's a release candidate, but at any rate it's *not* a full release), but you're not completely out of luck if you run into any issues.  That said, if you're on the fence, it might be worth holding off, as the actual release should be out sometime in the next few months, as both roadmaps place this occurring in the 1st quarter of this year.

Answer (score 4):

The version after EF6.x has not been shipped as RTM yet. Note that as per this [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144) it won't be EF7 but Entity Framework Core 1